# nuxtServerInit не работает в модулях vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

nuxtServerInit не срабатывает при использовании в модулях vuex.

```
async nuxtServerInit({commit}){
    await this.$axios
        .get(apiURL + '/section')
        .then((result) => {
            commit('SET_SECTION_LIST', result.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            commit('SET_ERRORS', error)
        })
}
```

К примеру при использовании в пространстве имен, в store/articles.js этот код не срабатывает, в store/index.js этот же код работает нормально.

Comment: Похоже, единственное решение:
If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to chain your module actions from there.